# Java: store to memory + numbers

Tags: java

Im having a function:

```
private void fixTurn(int turn)
```

And then I have:

```
  memory1 = memory1 + count;
```

Now, I would like to make, if turn is 2 it should:

```
  memory2 = memory2 + count;
```

I tried this:

```
  memory + turn = memory+turn + count;
```

But will it will not work, should i just go with an if statement?

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My polished crystal ball tells me, that you that you have some sort of game, that is organized in "turns" and you want to change something for a given turn ("fixTurn").

You may want to store the turns in a list. That's preferrable over an array, because a list can grow (or shrink) and allows adding more and more "turns".

Assuming, you have some class that models a turn and it's named `Turn`, declare the list like:

```
List<Turn> turns = new ArrayList<Turn>();
```

Then you can add turns to it:

```
turns.add(new Turn());
```

And now, if you have to change some parameter for a turn, do it like this:

```
private void fixTurn(int number) {
   Turn memory = turns.get(number);
   memory.setCount(memory.getCount()+count);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

No, you should use a collection of some form instead of having several separate variables. For example, you could use an array:

```
memory[turn] += count;
```

Answer (score 5):

Numerical indexes in variable names are generally something to be avoided.

Wanting to access such variables via the index is usually the sign of a novice programmer who hasn't gotten the point of arrays - because an array is exactly that, a bunch of variables that can be accessed via an index:

```
memory[turn] = memory[turn] + count;
```

or, shorter (using a compound assignment operator):

```
memory[turn] += count;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should rephrase your quesiton but I think you want to do something like this

```
private void fixTurn(int turn){

    if(turn == 1){//note can be replaced by a switch
       memory1 +=count;
    }else if(turn ==2){
       memory2 +=count;
    }
```

---

Edit: the solution proposed by John Skeet is better in terms of readability and adaptability and I would recommend it more

Comment: If he doesn't want an array, I would go for a switch at least.

Answer (score 1):

u have to write it as
memory += turn * count

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear about your question but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
memory += turn * count
```

Answer (score -2):

This syntax is not allowed in java

```
memory + turn = memory+turn + count;
```

Comment: not descriptive at all. Better to start with explnation of the fact, not with the fact itself.(-1)